# Java anotation to warn eclipse for unused methods

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any Java Eclipse annotation, what inform me (in Eclipse Ctrl + Space thingy) like:  "This method is there just because of extends and do nothing", and if its not how do I create it?

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? I don't think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@deprecated is the right tag to use

Comment: Well, ok then, I don't think it is a same meaning, but you have 6,684 reputation and I have 6, so you are probably smarter :D

Comment: Very wrong. @Deprecated is there only for deprecations, i.e., API methods that are no longer in use because of preferred replacements, too many errors in common usage, etc.  You leave an non-preferred method and deprecate it when you are leaving it there for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

@SuppressWarnings("unused") is useful for this.  There are other values for other suppressions too.  You should use this sparingly, only when you are absolutely sure it is needed.